# Finding that which sums to the smallest value

Tags: python, python-3.x

Is there a better way of doing the following in python:

```
m = float("inf")
for i in ((1,2,3),(1,3,1),(2,2,3),(0,2,2)):
    r = sum(i)
    if r < m:
        best = i
        m = r
print(best)
```

Where I'm trying to find the item in ((1,2,3),(1,3,1),(2,2,3),(0,2,2)) which sums to the smallest value.

The following is the best I can come up with:

```
data = ((1,2,3),(1,3,1),(2,2,3),(0,2,2))
sums = tuple(sum(i) for i in data)
print(data[sums.index(min(sums))])
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just use the built-in [**`min`**](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#min)

```
data = ((1,2,3),(1,3,1),(2,2,3),(0,2,2))
print(min(data, key=sum))
```

Comment: @user2357112 Nice! And you can even use key=lambda x: f(g(x)) is so desired.

Answer (score 0):

Another way, is to sort your tuple, based on the sum of each element than taking the first element which would be with least sum:

```
>>> t = ((1,2,3),(1,3,1),(2,2,3),(0,2,2))
>>> sorted(t, key=sum)[0]
(0, 2, 2)
```

Comment: Feasible, but `sorted` has time complexity `O(N log(N)` while `min` has time complexity `O(N)`

Comment: @Caridorc Wouldn't this be the required approach if there were multiple solutions?

Comment: @Baz yes, for more than one value you should sort it.